# Unity: Main Camera following player wants to be right side up

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

I have a player moving around a sphere and have my camera following the player. When I move past the poles at the absolute top or bottom of the sphere, the scene quickly spins around so that the up direction of the camera (and scene) remain at the top of the display. Is there a way to simply turn that off? I would rather the scene had no global concept of up or down, just relative up and down. If there isn't a simple way, is there a not so simple way to avoid the spinning? Here's my Update() code in case that helps. Thanks!

```
void Update()
    {
        Vector3 waypointTunnelDirection = Geometry.Scale(waypoints[waypointIndex] - transform.position, 0.01f);
        Vector3 waypointSurfaceStepPosition = Geometry.Scale(transform.position + waypointTunnelDirection, 0.5f);

        transform.position = Geometry.Scale(Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, waypointSurfaceStepPosition, maxSpeed), 0.5f);
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, waypoints[waypointIndex]) < 0.01f) {
            waypointIndex = (waypointIndex + 1) % waypoints.Length;
        }

        mainCamera.transform.position = Geometry.Scale(transform.position, 2.0f);
        Vector3 targetDirection = transform.position - mainCamera.transform.position;
        mainCamera.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.RotateTowards(mainCamera.transform.forward, targetDirection, 99, 99));
    }
```

Comment: Can you add a little explanation of your code to your question?

Comment: Does your player rotate properly around the sphere?

Comment: Why are you using 'mainCamera' in your update function?

Comment: Is this your camera or player update function?

Comment: Good questions. This is the update function for my player. The player at this point is a sphere so I'm not doing any re-orientation of it, but it does travel around the sphere properly. I'm using mainCamera in my player update function to re-orient the camera to always look "down" on the player like a drone flying directly above.

Comment: If you put this information in the question I can upvote your question

Comment: I posted an answer to your question, does this fix the problem you are having?  If not let me know about any issues and I will address them.

Comment: I've made some of the changes and am currently ignoring moving the camera. Doing the re-orient in Player.Update() is not working yet. I'll work some more and may have a follow-up later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all put the camera control logic in the camera component's update function.  By doing this you make your camera modular and so it becomes easier to reuse in another game for instance.

Instead of using a sphere for your temporary player, use any object that has an obvious top and front for testing and debugging purposes.  Then get your player to move around the world before working on the camera logic since the player orientation is necessary to properly orient the camera.

To move the player forward simply move it in it's transform.forward and then reorient the players "up" with Quaternion.LookRotation:

```
void Update()
{
    transform.position = transform.position + transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed;

    Vector3 up = transform.position;     // Assuming the center of the sphere world is (0,0,0)

    Vector3 forward = Vector3.Cross(transform.right, up);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(forward, up);
}
```

To Rotate your player, rotate it around its own transform.up Vector3:

```
transform.RotateAround(Vector3.zero, transform.up, angularSpeed*Time.deltaTime);
```

Now you can update your camera in it's update function:

```
public class Camera : MonoBehavior
{
    public GameObject player;
    public float camHeight;
    public float camDistance;

    void Update()
    {
        Transform pt = player.transform;

        // Set camera Position;
        Vector3 camOffset = -pt.forward * camDistance + pt.up * camHeight;
        transform.position = pt.position + camOffset;

        // Set camera orientation
        transform.LookAt(pt.position, pt.up);
    }
}
```

Comment: Made a few more corrections and ran in Unity.  Works good.

Comment: camDistance was the key here. Your code works great when camDistance is > 0. Using 0 for straight overhead still lets the camera rotate wildly sometimes, but even a value of 0.1 keeps that from happening. I appreciate the help. I learned a lot.

Comment: Great, glad I could help!